# Panda dataframe plot histogram from a row

Tags: dataframe, histogram

I have spectral data in rows in a panda dataframe. How can I plot each row as a histogram?

I currently use itterows to cycle through rows, but I cannot figure out how to plot the histogram using my data?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the only acceptable solution is to create a histogram for each row separately. First define bins in a separate variable:

```
bins=[-3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Then, e.g. for row 0 you can run:

```
df.iloc[0].hist(bins=bins)
```

An alternative: To have a number of such pictures in next to each other (horizontally), e.g. for 5 initial rows, you can run:

```
df.iloc[0:5].T.hist(bins=bins, sharey=True, layout=(1, 5), figsize=(12, 3))
```

I hope this helps.